# How To convert Pcollection<String> variable into String

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow

I have *PCollection<String>* of type String and I want to transform this to get values of specific column from BigQuery table. So I used *BigQueryIO.readTableRows* to get values from BigQuery.

Here is my Code:

```
     PCollection<TableRow> getConfigTable = pipeline.apply("read from Table",
            BigQueryIO.readTableRows().from("TableName"));

    RetrieveDestTableName retrieveDestTableName = new RetrieveDestTableName();
    PCollection<String> getDestTableName = getConfigTable.apply(ParDo.of(new DoFn<String,String>(){
        @ProcessElement
        public void processElement(ProcessContext c){
            c.output(c.element().get("ColoumnName").toString());
        }
    }));
```

As per above code I will get an output from ***getDestTableName*** of type PCollection<String> but I want this output in *String* variable.

Is there any way to convert ***PCollection<String>*** to ***String*** datatype variable so that I can able to use variable in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting a `PCollection<String>` to a `String` is not possible in the Apache Beam programming model. A `PCollection` simply describes the state of the pipeline at any given point. During development, you do not have literal access to the strings in the `PCollection`.

You can process the strings in a `PCollection` through transforms. However, it seems like you need the table configuration to construct the rest of the pipeline. You'll need to know the destination ahead of time or you can use [DynamicDestinations](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.3.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/DynamicDestinations.html) to determine which table to write to during pipeline execution. You cannot get the table configuration value from the `PCollection` and use it to further construct the pipeline.

Comment: Thanks @Andrew it works for me. Is it possible to get BigQuery Table schema information dynamically in _DynamicDestination_ transformation? Could you please explain me this with example it is really helpful for me.

Comment: @ShubhamR, the `DynamicDestinations` transform does not provide a way to dynamically retrieve `TableSchema`. Ideally, you want to provide all of the `TableSchema`s to the transform ahead of time so that the schema is not retrieve during execution time (overhead). In the `getSchema()` method, you might implement something as simple as an if-statement which determines which `TableSchema` to use based on the `destination: String` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want something like `JdbcIO.readAll()` but for BigQuery, allowing the read configuration(s) to be dynamically computed by the pipeline. This is currently not implemented for BigQuery, but it'd be a reasonable request.

Meanwhile your options are:

- Express what you're doing as a more complex BigQuery SQL query, and use a single `BigQueryIO.read().fromQuery()`
- Express the part of your pipeline where you extract the table of interest without the Beam API, instead using the BigQuery API directly, so you are operating regular Java variables instead of `PCollection`s.