# Apache Beam update current row values based on the values from previous row

Tags: java, apache-beam, apache-beam-io, apache-beam-internals

Apache Beam update values based on the values from the previous row

I have grouped the values from a CSV file. Here in the grouped rows, we find a few missing values which need to be updated based on the values from the previous row. If the first column of the row is empty then we need to update it by 0.

I am able to group the records, But unable to figure out a logic to update the values, How do I achieve this?

Records

| customerId | date | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| BS:89481 | 1/1/2012 | 100 |
| BS:89482 | 1/1/2012 |  |
| BS:89483 | 1/1/2012 | 300 |
| BS:89481 | 1/2/2012 | 900 |
| BS:89482 | 1/2/2012 | 200 |
| BS:89483 | 1/2/2012 |  |

Records on Grouping

| customerId | date | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| BS:89481 | 1/1/2012 | 100 |
| BS:89481 | 1/2/2012 | 900 |
| BS:89482 | 1/1/2012 |  |
| BS:89482 | 1/2/2012 | 200 |
| BS:89483 | 1/1/2012 | 300 |
| BS:89483 | 1/2/2012 |  |

Update missing values

| customerId | date | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| BS:89481 | 1/1/2012 | 100 |
| BS:89481 | 1/2/2012 | 900 |
| BS:89482 | 1/1/2012 | ***000*** |
| BS:89482 | 1/2/2012 | 200 |
| BS:89483 | 1/1/2012 | 300 |
| BS:89483 | 1/2/2012 | ***300*** |

Code Until Now:

```
public class GroupByTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("We are about to start!!");

        final File schemaFile = new File(
                "C:\\AI\\Workspace\\office\\lombok\\artifact\\src\\main\\resources\\schema_transform2.avsc");

        File csvFile = new File(
                "C:\\AI\\Workspace\\office\\lombok\\artifact\\src\\main\\resources\\CustomerRequest-case2.csv");
        Schema schema = new Schema.Parser().parse(schemaFile);

        Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create();

        // Reading schema
        org.apache.beam.sdk.schemas.Schema beamSchema = AvroUtils.toBeamSchema(schema);

        final PCollectionTuple tuples = pipeline

                // Reading csv input
                .apply("1", FileIO.match().filepattern(csvFile.getAbsolutePath()))

                // Reading files that matches conditions 
                .apply("2", FileIO.readMatches())

                // Reading schema and validating with schema and converts to row and returns
                // valid and invalid list
                .apply("3", ParDo.of(new FileReader(beamSchema)).withOutputTags(FileReader.validTag(),
                        TupleTagList.of(invalidTag())));

        // Fetching only valid rows
        final PCollection<Row> rows = tuples.get(FileReader.validTag()).setCoder(RowCoder.of(beamSchema));

        // Transformation
        //Convert row to KV
        final Group.CombineFieldsByFields<Row> combine = Group.<Row>byFieldNames("customerId", "date")
            .aggregateField("balance", Sum.ofDoubles(), "balances");

        final PCollection<Row> aggregagte = rows.apply(combine);

        PCollection<String> pOutput=aggregagte.apply(Select.flattenedSchema()).apply(ParDo.of(new RowToString()));
        
                        
        
        pipeline.run().waitUntilFinish();
        System.out.println("The end");

    }

    private static String getColumnValue(String columnName, Row row, Schema sourceSchema) {
        String type = sourceSchema.getField(columnName).schema().getType().toString().toLowerCase();
        LogicalType logicalType = sourceSchema.getField(columnName).schema().getLogicalType();
        if (logicalType != null) {
            type = logicalType.getName();
        }

        switch (type) {
        case "string":
            return row.getString(columnName);
        case "int":
            return Objects.requireNonNull(row.getInt32(columnName)).toString();
        case "bigint":
            return Objects.requireNonNull(row.getInt64(columnName)).toString();
        case "double":
            return Objects.requireNonNull(row.getDouble(columnName)).toString();
        case "timestamp-millis":
            return Instant.ofEpochMilli(Objects.requireNonNull(row.getDateTime("eventTime")).getMillis()).toString();

        default:
            return row.getString(columnName);

        }
    }



}
```

**Modified Code:**
Original code

```
final Group.CombineFieldsByFields<Row> combine = Group.<Row>byFieldNames("customerId", "date")
        .aggregateField("amount", Sum.ofDoubles(), "balances");
```

Grouping by customerID

```
class ToKV extends DoFn<Row, KV<String, Row>> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8093837716944809689L;
    String columnName1 = null;

    @ProcessElement
    public void processElement(ProcessContext context) {
        Row row = context.element();
        org.apache.beam.sdk.schemas.Schema schema = row.getSchema();
        context.output(KV.of(row.getValue(columnName1).toString(), row));
    }

    public void setColumnName1(String columnName1) {
        this.columnName1 = columnName1;
    }


}
```

Grouping by customerID:

```
ToKV toKV = new ToKV();
toKV.setColumnName1("ID");
PCollection<KV<String, Row>> kvRows = rows.apply(ParDo.of(toKV)).setCoder(KvCoder.of(StringUtf8Coder.of(), rows.getCoder()));
    
    
PCollection<KV<String,Iterable<Row>>> groupedKVRows = kvRows.apply(GroupByKey.<String,Row>create());
```

// Trying to grouping by date

```
    PCollection<Row> outputRow = 
            groupedKVRows
            .apply(ParDo.of(new GroupByDate()))
            .setCoder(RowCoder.of(AvroUtils.toBeamSchema(schema)));
```

How to write the logic to convert Iterable to pCollection so that the date can be sorted.

```
class GroupByDate extends DoFn<KV<String,Iterable<Row>>, Row> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1345126662309830332L;

    @ProcessElement
    public void processElement(ProcessContext context) {
        String strKey = context.element().getKey();
        Iterable<Row> rows = context.element().getValue();
        
    
        
        
    }
```

Avro schema:

```
{
  "type" : "record",
  "name" : "Entry",
  "namespace" : "transform",
  "fields" : [  {
    "name" : "customerId",
    "type" : [ "string", "null" ]
  }, {
    "name" : "date",
    "type" : [ "string", "null" ],
    "logicalType": "date"
    
  }, {
    "name" : "amount",
    "type" : [ "double", "null" ]
  } ]
}
```

**Update To convert PCollection to Row[]**

```
class KVToRow extends DoFn<KV<String, Iterable<Row>>, Row[]> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1345126662309830332L;

    @ProcessElement
    public void processElement(ProcessContext context) {
        String strKey = context.element().getKey();
        List<Row> rowList = new ArrayList();
        Iterable<Row> rowValue = context.element().getValue();
        rowValue.forEach(data -> {
            rowList.add(data);

        });
        Row[] rowArray = new Row[rowList.size()-1];
        rowArray=rowList.toArray(rowArray);
        context.output(rowArray);
    }
}
```

**Suggested Code**

```
Row[] rowArray = Iterables.toArray(rows, Row.class);
```

**Error:**

The method toArray(Iterable<? extends T>, Class) in the type Iterables is not applicable for the arguments (PCollection, Class)

**Convert iterable to array**

```
Row[] rowArray =  groupedKVRows.apply(ParDo.of(new KVToRow()));
```

**Error:**

Multiple markers at this line
- Type mismatch: cannot convert from PCollection<Row[]>
to Row[]
- 1 changed line, 2 deleted

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Beam does not provide any order guarantees, so you will have to group them as you did.

But as far as I can understand from your case, you need to group by `customerId`. After that, you can apply a PTransform like ParDo to sort the grouped Rows by `date` and fill missing values however you wish.

**Example sorting by converting to Array**

```
static class SortAndForwardFillFn extends DoFn<KV<String, Iterable<Row>>> {

    @ProcessElement
    public void processElement(@Element KV<String, Iterable<Row>> element, OutputReceiver<KV<String, Iterable<Row>>> outputReceiver) {

        // Create a formatter for parsing dates
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

        // Convert iterable to array
        Row[] rowArray = Iterables.toArray(rows, Row.class);

        // Sort array using dates
        Arrays
            .sort(
                rowArray,
                Comparator
                .comparingLong(row -> formatter.parseDateTime(row.getString("date")).getMillis())
        );

        // Store the last amount
        Double lastAmount = 0.0;

        // Create a List for storing sorted and filled rows
        List<Row> resultRows = new ArrayList<>(rowArray.length);

        // Iterate over the array and fill in the missing parts
        for (Row row : rowArray) {

            // Get current amount
            Double currentAmount = row.getDouble("amount");

            // If null, fill the previous value and add to results, 
            // otherwise add as it is
            resultRows.add(...);
        }

        // Output using the output receiver
        outputReceiver
            .output(
                KV.of(element.getKey(), resultRows)
            )
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Earlier in my code, I had done the grouping by customerID and date simultaneously, Now, based on your suggestion, I have grouped the rows by customerID alone and I am struggling with grouping the records by date.  Kindly help me with a sudo code!!

Comment: I have updated the question to include modified code!!

Comment: You don’t have to convert values to PCollection for sorting. Simply, sort `Iterable<Row>` in any way suitable in Java (`stream.sorted()`, `Arrays.sort()`, etc).

Comment: What is the type of the `date` field in your Avro schema?

Comment: Date field is of   "type" : [ "string", "null" ],
    "logicalType": "date"

Comment: @User27854 I have added an example code piece. I think you can continue from there

Comment: Row[] rowArray = Iterables.toArray(rows, Row.class);  here rows is a PCollection object and we wont be able to convert to rowArray? I have tried that manually. I even tried by creating an anonymous ParDo class. But it we will still end end up with a PCollection object

Comment: Its due to these running in a distributed environment. Also, I have updated the code where I had convert the PCollection to Row[] to update the PCollection.

 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49130931/how-to-convert-pcollectionstring-variable-into-string

Comment: This answer looks quite good, although I recommend structuring it as a [DoFn](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#pardo) for clarity. That would help clarify input types especially. For example, from context it looks like `rows` is meant to be an `Iterable<Row>`, which is an element input to a DoFn. (I can edit the post to do this if you prefer.)

Comment: @DanielOliveira, Apologies that I missed your comment for a few days. There as no notifications on this.  I did try to implement a DoFn function but the return type will again be a PCollection<Row> or PCollection<Row[]>.

Comment: Could you please update the past accordingly!!

Comment: @User27854 A return type of PCollection<Row[]> is the expected return type with this approach. The elements should now sorted arrays of forward filled records, and from there you can do any followup work that you want.

Comment: @DanielOliveira I couldn't check SO notifications for some time. I structured it as a DoFn for future reference. Thank you.